# Upgrading IdentityServer4 v2 to v3 scope error

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I took my old config code from my previous core 2 project with identity server and moved it to a new core 3.1 project. Everything seems to be working, database is created and most stuff "looks" right so far. The first problem I have encountered is a scope error when hitting the token endpoint. I get an invalid scope error. I'm not sure why this is not working, here is the log of the call to /connect/token.

```
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
[19:34:49 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Start token request.
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Start client validation
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser
Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser
Start parsing for secret in post body
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser
Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretParser
Secret id found: myapp_mobile
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
myapp_mobile found in database: True
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client myapp_mobile succeeded.
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator
Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator
Client validation success
[19:34:49 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
{"ClientId": "myapp_mobile", "AuthenticationMethod": "SharedSecret", "Category": "Authentication", "Name": "Client Authentication Success", "EventType": "Success", "Id": 1010, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "80000020-0000-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb", "TimeStamp": "2020-02-08T00:34:49.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 22424, "LocalIpAddress": "10.37.129.3:443", "RemoteIpAddress": "10.37.129.2", "$type": "ClientAuthenticationSuccessEvent"}
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start token request validation
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
Start resource owner password token request validation
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found [] identity scopes in database
[19:34:49 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["myapp_api_resource", "myapp_api"] API scopes in database
[19:34:49 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator
Requested scope not allowed: email
[19:34:49 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator
{"ClientId": "myapp_mobile", "ClientName": "myapp Mobile App", "GrantType": "password", "Scopes": null, "AuthorizationCode": null, "RefreshToken": null, "UserName": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "Tenant": null, "IdP": null, "Raw": {"client_id": "myapp_mobile", "client_secret": "***REDACTED***", "username": "testguy1", "password": "***REDACTED***", "grant_type": "password"}, "$type": "TokenRequestValidationLog"}
[19:34:49 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
{"ClientId": "myapp_mobile", "ClientName": "myapp Mobile App", "RedirectUri": null, "Endpoint": "Token", "SubjectId": null, "Scopes": null, "GrantType": "password", "Error": "invalid_scope", "ErrorDescription": null, "Category": "Token", "Name": "Token Issued Failure", "EventType": "Failure", "Id": 2001, "Message": null, "ActivityId": "80000020-0000-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb", "TimeStamp": "2020-02-08T00:34:49.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 22424, "LocalIpAddress": "10.37.129.3:443", "RemoteIpAddress": "10.37.129.2", "$type": "TokenIssuedFailureEvent"}
```

I get that "Requests scope not allowed: email", I have no idea why. I am requesting no scopes so I should receive all of them. Is this something that is an asp.net core identity setting that I missed? The client scopes table has email for my client so any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Who would downgrade this and not at least comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple if anyone else has this problem.

Probably somewhere in my old setup I manually added the IdentityResource configs to the database or they never made it into my final database seeding code. Once I added those the token endpoint started to work.